# Firefox 8 disabled=disabled

Tags: jquery, html, firefox-8

I have just finished developing a web app but I have a really annoying annoying issue concerning the disabled property in firefox 8.

It appears as though `disabled=disabled` is not valid and therefore my hyperlink will not render as disabled.

I am trying this out on the following html code:
I have tried a number of different jQuery commands just to make sure it was not a specific method of me trying to disable to hyperlink.

```
<a id="continue_link" href="/">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //$('#continue_link').attr("disabled", "true");
    //$('#continue_link').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#continue_link').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#continue_link').prop("disabled", "true");
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disabled` is not (and never was) an attribute of the `a` element. To prevent a links default behaviour, the simplest method in jQuery is to use either `return false` or more specifically `e.preventDefault()`.

Try this:

```
$("#continue_link").click(function(e) {
    if (myCondition == "something") {
        // stop the link
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("I'm sorry. I can't let you do that, Dave.");
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh rite, I thought this was the case. What is to be used instead if i do not want it to be enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You want to either add this to the  tag as an attribute:

```
onclick="return false;"
```

Or this in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#continue_link').click(function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

disabled is not an attribute that is valid on an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

The following css style this will solve the issue in firefox

```
a[disabled] {
color: gray !important;
cursor: default !important;
text-decoration: none;
}
```